# Shiny - Limit date range selection to X number of days

Tags: r, date, shiny, shinywidgets

I need an excact 2 day range for ShinyWidgets **airDatepickerInput**.
Meaning I can only select 1 day in front of the first date selected.

How to update maxDate and minDate options for input$Dates[2] to be reactive and equal input$Dates[1] + 1

Are there better methods? How do you use **updateAirDateInput** ?

```
# Libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


# UI
ui <- navbarPage(title = "Title - V1.0",
                 tabPanel("Tab 1",
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                                         airDatepickerInput(inputId = "Dates",
                                                            multiple = 2,
                                                            range = TRUE)),
                            mainPanel())))

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

# Create a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

```
daterangepicker(
  inputId = "Dates",
  label = "Select Dates",
  start = as_date(Sys.Date()-60),
  end = as_date(Sys.Date()),
  min = '2021-01-01',
  max = Sys.Date(),
  options = daterangepickerOptions(maxSpan = list("days" = 2)),
  ranges = list("Today" = Sys.Date(),
                "Yesterday" = Sys.Date() - 1,
                "Yesterday & Today" = c(Sys.Date() - 1, Sys.Date()),
                "Last 7 days" = c(Sys.Date() - 6, Sys.Date())))
```

Refer here for basic and advanced examples:

https://github.com/trafficonese/daterangepicker/tree/master/inst/examples